# Having issues with ag-grid search textbox

Tags: angular, angular6, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am currently using the ag-grid within my angular 7 application.

ag-grid version details given below:

```
"ag-grid": "^18.1.2",
"ag-grid-angular": "^20.0.0",
"ag-grid-community": "^20.0.0",
"ag-grid-enterprise": "^20.0.0",
```

I am facing some issues while using the ag-grid.

The issues are given below:

issue #1:

I have a textbox on top of the ag-grid.

I have ag-grid with columns-Environment, region, description, age.

When user type a text, say 'Dev', ag-grid displays the records with 'Dev' keyword across all the columns. 
Instead of searching 'Dev' keyword from all the 4 columns, I need to search only 'Environment and Region' columns in the ag-grid.

issue #2:

I have a data.json, which has url links in it. I binded these url data to the ag-grid. The url is displayed as full text with link in each row.

Instead of full text url, I need to introduce an 'Open' option in each cells of the 'URL column' in the ag-grid. When user clicks the 'Open' in each row, corresponding 'URL link row from the data.json' should be binded and opened in new tab.

I used Angular 7 
Json-Server(fake url-since my data is local json, I hosted it as a fake api using json-server api)

I used ag-grid version details given below:

```
"ag-grid": "^18.1.2",
"ag-grid-angular": "^20.0.0",
"ag-grid-community": "^20.0.0",
"ag-grid-enterprise": "^20.0.0"
```

issue #3:

I have a sample Json file and created a fack api call using json-server. Could you please assist me by doing a CRUD application in angular 7(without db or web api). ie., I will consume the json file from fack api call, and do the CRUD operation.

I can able to read the json file and bind to ag-grid, only issue is with edit operation.

Just if any POC on editing json records from angular 7(ag-grid) it will be helpful

issue 4:

to display logged in user at the top right of the angular 7 application

Comment: Could you share some of the code or better a plunker/stackblitz demo of the code you are running.

Comment: my office doesnt have access to plunker.

Comment: issue #1:

import { AgGridNg2 } from 'ag-grid-angular';import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';import "ag-grid-enterprise";
 @ViewChild('agGrid') agGrid: AgGridNg2;
this.colDefs = [
  defined column definition-have 10 columns here, need to search only from 2 columns
  ]
}
<input " type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchValue">
<ag-grid-angular 
    [columnDefs]="colDefs"
    (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)" 
    [rowData]="rowData"
    >
</ag-grid-angular>

Comment: issue #2:

data.json:
[{
  "regions": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "code": "CZ",
      "name": "Czech Republic",
      "url": "http://www.google.co,m"
    }
}]

this.colDefs = [
      {headerName: 'URL', name:'url', field: 'url', sortable: true,}
  ]

on grid bind:

this.http.get('http://localhost/regions').subscribe(data=>{
      params.api.setRowData(data)
      params.api.sizeColumnsToFit()
    });